# Trying to allow HTTP on a server that forces HTTPS

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf

## RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

Code above works fine, but I want to add an exception for URL's similar to:
abc.domain.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl

Above URL should load with HTTP

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/api/soap/$ [NC]
ReWriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^wsdl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```